# How change API URL in iOS Application without change code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

How can I change the address for the API in the application (iOS app) without changing the application code.

For example libraries for traffic redirect, or other ways.

I would like to redirect all traffic from the application to a different url.
I have the source code is available, but I would not want to change them.

For network use NSURLConnection / CFNetwork.

If it possible to implement it?

Comment: Are you consuming a web service?

Comment: @NickWeaver,
Yes, I use the auto-builder server.

And I'd like to change the API Url (ex. on DEBUG) during the build the project.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle this is with a config file that's built into your app. Have a config class (singleton) to provide an interface for your app to access these properties. On top of such a simple premise you can build out to add features as rich as you like. For example, here are some features you may wish to build based on this:

- Store multiple addresses in the config file and create a "test-mode" interface to select which one is currently in use (and even allow entering arbitrary free-form text to set custom values). The config class will return the current one, so other parts of your app need not care about config state, or test-mode settings, they only access the `currentAddress` property.
- Download new config files and use those instead of the built-in one.
- Create some kind of overridable settings structure (user settings, admin settings, debug settings).